# Drupal CAS redirection after login is failed

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I have been working on CAS SSO with drupal 7 and the authentication perfectly works and cas redirect to drupal when I install drupal and CAS in different machine. But when I put both drupal portal and the CAS server in the same machine and tried to login. It go to cas to authenticate and after it returns from drupal I see the dead white screen does anybody help?